# Iterating over c# HashTable and changing the value. Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, hashtable

I am trying to iterate over a HashTable and update the value provided it passes some conditions. Here is the code.

```
public static Hashtable AssembliesGlobal= new Hashtable();

public static void populateHash(){

   NDepend.Path.IAbsolutePath assemblyName; 
   NDepend.Path.IAbsolutePath projectName;

   for (int i = 0; i < someList.Count(); i++)
      {

         if (someList[i].AssembliesUsed.Count() > 0)
            {
                assemblyName = getAssemblyQuery[i].a.FilePath;
                if (getAssemblyQuery[i].a.VisualStudioProjectFilePath != null)
                {
                    List<IAbsolutePath> thirdPartyList = new List<IAbsolutePath>();
                    projectName = getAssemblyQuery[i].a.VisualStudioProjectFilePath;
                    thirdPartyList.Add(assemblyName);
                    AssembliesGlobal.Add(projectName, thirdPartyList);
                }

            }
        }
     }


public static void parseCsproj()
{

    foreach (IAbsoluteFilePath key in AssembliesGlobal.Keys)
    {
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(key.FileInfo.FullName);
        XmlNodeList references = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("ProjectReference");
        XmlNodeList hintReferences = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("HintPath");
        if (references.Count >= 1 || hintReferences.Count >= 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < references.Count; i++)
            {
                string path = references[i].Attributes[0].Value;
                if(path.Contains("3rdParty")){
                    AssembliesGlobal[key] = path;
                }

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < hintReferences.Count; i++)
            {
                string path = hintReferences[i].InnerText;
                if (path.Contains("3rdParty"))
                {
                    AssembliesGlobal[key] = path;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AssembliesGlobal is a hashtable with the structure of:

`AssembliesGlobal = {key => []}`

I would like to append to the array that is the value of key. After running the debugger in VS I keep getting a Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. error. I am aware that you cannot iteratively update a HashTable and I am wondering what a work around may be in this context. I new to this language.

Comment: It appears, that by "hash table" you mean a `Dictionary<IAbsoluteFilePath, string[]>` or `Dictionary<IAbsoluteFilePath, List<string>>` (desired) but in your code it really appears to be a `Dictionary<IAbsoluteFilePath, string>`.

Comment: @stakx Perhaps this is my problem? I initialized this as a global variable like this public static Hashtable AssembliesGlobal= new Hashtable();

Comment: Sorry mate, I didn't even realise there was an actual type called `Hashtable`, as I haven't used non-generic collection types for several years now. Perhaps take a look at the types defined in `System.Collections.Generic`, in particular `Dictionary<,>` -- they're somewhat safer and easier to work with, because the compiler / Visual Studio Intellisense can provide more guidance since there's more type information available about keys and values.

Comment: @stakx no worries. I am going to change up the dictionary definition so it will be generic. I am new to this language so defining types and what not on initialization is also new. Thank you for your input!

Comment: At a glance I don't really see anything wrong with what you're doing.  I've only seen issues when iterating certain Types when I'm in a foreach loop and I need to assign the item to a local variable.  As a starting point I'd switch to Dictionary<,> as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your comment on my comment above, is this what you're after (bearing in mind it's a stripped down example).

```
var AssembliesGlobal = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
AssembliesGlobal.Add("Steve", new List<string> { "1", "2", "3"});
foreach (var key in AssembliesGlobal.Keys)
{
    AssembliesGlobal[key].Add("4");
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is the answer! Thank you!

Comment: You said you're new to the language.  As long as you're using some IDE with intellisense whenever keying away keep an eye on the popups for what the return types are.  Typing the initial [ is like a method when you press ( and you'll see what the return type of the expression is and then you can tack on any method of that return type inline which is why Add() appears if your value type of the Dictionary is List.  If it's actually an array then you can't add to an array, only change existing elements.  To grow an array you need to reallocate and copy to a new array and overwrite the old value.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a copy of the list to iterate over, by casting and adding a `.ToList()`:

```
foreach (var key in AssembliesGlobal.Keys.Cast<IAbsoluteFilePath>().ToList())
```

Note that you need the `.Cast` because `Hashtable` is non-generic. As others have mentioned, the modern way to do this is `Dictionary<K,V>`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am getting this error System.Collection.Icollection does not contain a definition for for 'ToList()' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type System.Collection.Icollection could be found. I have edited my question to show how I originally populated the hash

Comment: @Rob I have that imported and still the error remains.

Comment: @jshaf Might I suggest using `Dictionary<,>` rather than `Hashtable`? This would allow the above code to work, and provide additional type-safety. Otherwise, the correct solution would be: `AssembliesGlobal.Keys.Cast<IAbsoluteFilePath>.ToList()`

Comment: Yes, just noticed that it's not a `Dictionary<K,V>` but non-generic `Hashtable`. Updated my answer, but I'd also recommend using generic types like `Dictionary`.

Comment: Note: *routinely* dumping a hash-table (or just the keys) into a list is probably not ideal; there are scenarios where it will be fine, and there are scenarios where that will murder performance

Comment: Switch to a Dictionary and you should be able to do this:
foreach (var key in AssembliesGlobal.Keys)
{
    AssembliesGlobal[key] = <New Value>;
}

Comment: I'm not sure that ToList() actually "dumps" to a list.  My understanding is that with reference types in the original structure ToList() creates a list with each item as a reference original instances.

Comment: @StephenYork no, you will still need to create a copy of the `Keys` list. And correct, there's no deep copy created by `ToList()` if it's a reference type. Still, if the table is large, it could impact performance (I don't know if it's significantly worse than iterating over the keys in the first place - that's not the normal use case for a hashtable/dictionary).

Comment: @StephenYork so I have tried what you recommended, however my goal is to append to an existing value that is an array. So something like this AssembliesGlobal[key] = [Item2] would actually return a hash with a value of an array. So this AssembliesGlobal variable would essentially look like {key => [item1, item2]}.

Comment: So don't make it an array, make it a List so it can be added to...Dictionary<thekey, List<theItemtype>> and when you do AssembliesGlobal[key] you have the List so you can call.Add(...) like so AssembliesGlobal[key].Add(theNewItemInTheList)